# How to handle consecutive money-transfer requests(within sec/ms) from the client, at the REST API level

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, request, banking

I am trying to write a Banking Application Transfer REST API. I have used SpringMVC, JDBCTemplate to develop the same.I am sending a POST request with the payload(fromAccountID, toAccountID, amount) in JSON format.

If user by-mistakenly clicks on the transfer button more than once (Assuming this is not handled on the UI) and same payload is sent to the API as JSON :

1.) How to ensure that only the first request is processed?

2.) How should the rest of the duplicate requests be handled?

3.)The user could genuinely be trying to transfer the same amount again to the same destination Account, so the duplicates should be handled for say a couple of minutes only. How can this be achieved?

4.) How is this scenario handled in real-time banking Applications?

I am in the initial phase of learning to write REST API's so any guidance around this usecase will be appreciated.

Comment: Look up "POST-redirect-GET"

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, please find below comments for the same;

In this scenario we need to apply the check at interface itself.

It the request is coming from button then it can be easily handled with onclick event and a simple confirm dialogue box

If there is a requirement of NOT asking user confirmation and send request to API to process payment then u can store previous request somewhere(array or session) and if matches then ask user confirmation.

This is how you can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A RESTful way to solve this problem is to ensure that you only use idempotent requests. An idempotent request is more or less defined as:

> The state on the server after doing an request once will be identical to doing same the request n times.

There are a few HTTP requests that are explicitly defined as idempotent, such as:

- PUT
- DELETE
- GET

So if you can design your application in a way where you use `PUT` to create new transfers, and `PUT` is implemented in correctly, receiving the same request n times should have no side-effects.

This is not always particularly easy though, because if you are 'creating' a new transfer resource with `PUT`, the implication is that the client must determine what the new URI of the transfer will be. A client could for example generate a UUID for the url.

I think this approach is by far the most desirable. You can automatically have the server throw an error if the transfer resource already exists, by including an `If-None-Match: *` header. If you use this header you can return `412 Precondition Failed` is the resource already existed.

My guess is that your intuition would have been to use `POST` for creating new transfers, but the idea that `POST = create & PUT = update` is incorrect. `PUT` should be used for both creation and updating resources, *if* the path can be known by the client.